# Algorithm for sensor network distribution

Tags: algorithm

I need an algorithm for distributing sensors in a given space. The space might have obstacles. Each sensor has a reach radius (for communicating with each other) and I need to cover the entire area, considering the radius. The goal is to minimize the number of sensors used and maximize the area covered. Anyone?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the trade-off between area covered and number of sensors used. Otherwise if you have almost all the area already covered except for a small bit, you won't know whether or not to add an extra sensor to cover the little bit. You could rephrase your problem as covering the maximal amount of area for a fixed given number of sensors. If you have a visible region which is a polygonal region with holes (obstacles), I believe your problem is solved and you just need to review the literature. If you have arbitrary defined spaces and obstacles then I don't know if a known solution exists.

Comment: Well, the number of sensors is not fixed. Actually, given any area, the algorithm is supposed to compute the minimum number of sensors required to fill the entire space, so limiting the number of sensors is not an option because that's precisely what I want the algorithm to do.